# Regex allow empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to apply a regex in which a number can be formatted to two decimal places, I've been able to achieve this. But I am unable to delete the first character in the string because my test will fail if there is no match. How can I modify this regex to support the deletion of the entire value?

`/^[0-9]+(\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$/`

https://codesandbox.io/s/k2qlq0w68r

Comment: I don't get it. Can't you just make the first part optional?  `^([0-9]+)?(\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$`, you're already getting "number" validation from the `input` field itself so "." won''t be valid either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific thing that you're doing (input validation), you can probably just eschew your regex altogether and just use [`<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) with a `step`:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

You can check the [`validity` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) to check if anything is incorrect. I believe something like `document.getElementById("id").checkValidity()` will give you what you want.

See also: [Validating forms using JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript) and [Form Validation Part 2: The Constraint Validation API (JavaScript)](https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-2-constraint-validation-api-javascript/).

---

If you still wish to use the regex, it's probably easier to separate the only-decimal and part non-decimal cases:

```
/^(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$/
```

This matches the following numbers: `100`, `12.5`, `10.`, `8.51`, `.67`, `.0`

But rejects the following: `.032`, `.`, [empty string]

I would recommend that you run the validation *after* the user types in the number, not as they are currently typing it in. Otherwise, it will be impossible for them to type `.01`, as your regex will reject them when pressing `.`.

Comment: this also breaks the single decimal validation

Comment: @huge-iguana not sure what you mean by "single decimal validation"; is it not one of the cases I've listed? Also, is using `step` not sufficient?

Comment: `step="0.01"` only refers to the html counter, it doesn't do any input restriction.

Comment: @huge-iguana Looks like the input gets rejected to me (see [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBqXdz)).

Comment: thank you. thank you. you are correct, i was mistaken. apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regex that also accepts the empty string:

`/^([0-9]+(\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?|)$/`

But I would suggest to you to not assume that the input is valid while the user puts it into your input but instead validate the value after the user is done editing (e.g. by using a loose focus event).

Comment: I don't believe the OP wants to match the empty string, but rather, to match numbers like `.12` (without a leading zero) without matching strings like `.` and empty string.

Comment: yes, this works but now it breaks the single decimal validation.

Comment: How else would you make it possible to remove the only char in the input? That is why i suggested to use validation after the user is finished editing (with your regex, btw).

Comment: unfortunately i need to validate while the user is typing.